# Sci-Fi dystopian book, man wakes up in a pod, people with particular skill appear at his door when needed

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

I read this book in 2004 or 2005, it was an assigned reading but ignited my love for dystopian societies.

I believe it started out with someone who wakes up in a pod, I think he was eventually sent to an apartment that was being monitored. Everytime he needed someone with a particular skill someone he knew from his previous society would appear at the door. There was a restricted area referred to as the RA.

I do remember the group had to overcome their preconceived notions/initial dislike of each other in order to work together to escape their essential enslavement. The main character may have gotten into trouble which is why he was placed in a pod in the first place.

Comment: Hi there! That's some good info already but could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Perhaps the most important one - when would it have been published, or at least when did you read it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you be more specific about the year you read this?  We don't know how old you are, so we don't know when you were in high school.  (Some pointers for good questions can be found [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question).)

Comment: I read this in 2004 or 2005.